# Como colocar uma fonte externa no meu aplicativo?

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu estou tentando colocar uma fonte personalizada no meu app, mas estou tendo muitos erros.

Já tentei usar o PixlUI, já tentei diversos códigos diferentes e sempre da erro, ou o aplicativo é executado, porém da crash ***(app Parou)***.

Este é o código que estou tentando colocar dentro do *MainActivity.java*:

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
    "fonts/watermelon.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Este é o código do *MainActivity*:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
    "fonts/watermelon.ttf");
    tx.setTypeface(custom_font);                
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();}
                }

public void opensecondactivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
       } 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , AboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
          }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;               
            }
     }
}
```

Com esse código o Eclipse não declara nenhum erro, porém quando ele executa a Activity ele da erro e o aplicativo é fechado sozinho. O que fazer?

*Só pra constar, a fonte está na pasta "assets/fonts"*

***Debug:***

```
New_configuration [Android Application] 
    DalvikVM [localhost:8612]   
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
            <VM does not provide monitor information>   
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2195    
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2245 
            ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 135    
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1196  
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
            Looper.loop() line: 136 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5017    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 779  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 595 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
        Thread [<11> Timer-0] (Running)
```

***Logcat:***

```
06-14 09:58:59.484: W/ActivityThread(1243): Application com.akzonobel.malote is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-14 09:58:59.494: I/System.out(1243): Sending WAIT chunk
06-14 09:58:59.584: I/dalvikvm(1243): Debugger is active
06-14 09:58:59.694: I/System.out(1243): Debugger has connected
06-14 09:58:59.744: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:58:59.954: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:00.154: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:00.354: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:00.564: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:00.764: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:00.994: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:01.194: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:01.394: I/System.out(1243): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-14 09:59:01.594: I/System.out(1243): debugger has settled (1348)
06-14 09:59:02.424: D/(1243): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8f54e48, tid 1243
06-14 09:59:02.514: W/EGL_emulation(1243): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-14 09:59:02.524: D/OpenGLRenderer(1243): Enabling debug mode 0
06-14 09:59:03.054: W/EGL_emulation(1243): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-14 09:59:06.384: D/AndroidRuntime(1243): Shutting down VM
06-14 09:59:06.384: W/dalvikvm(1243): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aa8ba8)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243): Process: com.akzonobel.malote, PID: 1243
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.akzonobel.malote/com.akzonobel.malote.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at com.akzonobel.malote.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-14 09:59:06.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     ... 11 more
06-14 10:00:38.184: I/Process(1243): Sending signal. PID: 1243 SIG: 9
```

**EDIT - SOLUÇÃO:**
Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram! A solução era implementar o código dentro do `public View onCreateView`. Veja como ficou:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/laouib.TTF");
        txt.setTypeface(font); 

        return rootView;
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54747/discussion-on-question-by-renan-como-colocar-uma-fonte-externa-no-meu-aplicativo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ler fontes externas, eu coloquei as fontes na raiz da pasta asset e criei um classe "FontChanger" que só tem métodos para mudar as fontes. Todos os métodos são estáticos para que não precise instanciar a classe. A única coisa que passo ao método e o Context.
Implementacao do metodo dentro da classe FontChanger :

```
public static Typeface setRobotoRegular(Context context)
{
     return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"roboto_regular.ttf");
}
```

mudando a fonte de um textView que tenha em minha aplicacao:

```
meuTextView.setTypeFace(FontChanger.setRobotoRegular(context));
```

Comment: Testei este código, mas ele fala isso: `context cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Renan ai eu dei o exemplo de uma variável do tipo Contexto que tenho e tem o nome context. se voce esta em um Fragment faca 
Context context=getActivity();

Comment: Finalmente consegui! Você me deu a luz! Bastava implementar o código dentro do `public View onCreateView`. =D Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Clique com o botão direito na pasta "res" > New>Android Resource Diretory.
Ponha um nome de sua preferência no diretório e em "Resource type" selecione o tipo "font" e aperte em ok. 
Depois disso é só copiar suas fontes para dentro da pasta criada.

Obs.: Antes de copiar as fontes, renomeie e tire todos os caracteres especiais e traços, pois o Android Studio não aceita arquivos com nomes assim.

Exemplo: DS-DIGITAL.TFF >>>>>> dsdigital.tff!

Fonte: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]